# Stationary linear random fields

Tags: probability-theory, time-series

Murry Rosenblatt in his 2000 book "Gaussian and Non-Gaussian Linear Time Series and Random Fields" introduces stationary linear random fields with d-dimensional vector indices thus:
\begin{equation}
x_\textbf{t} =\sum_{\textbf{j}} a_{\textbf{j}} \xi_{\textbf{t} - \textbf{j} }  = (a * \xi)_{\textbf{t}}
\end{equation}
where

\begin{equation}
\sum_{\textbf{j}}a_{\textbf{j}} < \infty
\end{equation}
and where subscripts $\textbf{t}$ and $\textbf{j}$ are $d$-vectors and the summation extends over all lattice points in $Z^d$ with the $\xi$'s independent, identically distributed random variables, $E\xi \equiv 0$, $0 < E \xi_{\textbf{j}}^2 < \infty$.

If the indices were one dimensional this would say that $x_t$ is equal to the sum of $j$ past values of $\xi_t$, each weighted by $a_j$.

What does it mean when the indices are multidimensional?

If I think of it in two dimensions then each $x_{\textbf{t}}$ is a point on a grid and each of those $x_{\textbf{t}}$ points are determined by the summing of a set of points on another grid containing $\xi_{\textbf{t}}$ (with each $\xi_{\textbf{t}- {\textbf{j}} }$ weighted by $a_{\textbf{j}}$). This also means which points on the $\xi_{\textbf{t}}$ grid that are summed to determine each $\xi_{\textbf{t}}$ is determined by $\textbf{j}$.

My (experimental) example:

If $\textbf{t} \in \{   \begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 0 \end{bmatrix}, \begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 1 \end{bmatrix} \} $ and 
$\textbf{j} \in \{   \begin{bmatrix} 0 \\ 0 \end{bmatrix}, \begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 1 \end{bmatrix} \}$

then for $\textbf{t} = \begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 0 \end{bmatrix}$ we have
\begin{equation} 
x_{\begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 0 \end{bmatrix}} = 
a_{\begin{bmatrix} 0 \\ 0 \end{bmatrix}} \xi_{\begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 0 \end{bmatrix}} + 
a_{\begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 1 \end{bmatrix}} 
\xi_{\begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 0 \end{bmatrix} - \begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 1 \end{bmatrix}}
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
= a_{\begin{bmatrix} 0 \\ 0 \end{bmatrix}} \xi_{\begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 0 \end{bmatrix}} + 
a_{\begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 1 \end{bmatrix}} 
\xi_{\begin{bmatrix} 0 \\ -1 \end{bmatrix} } \end{equation}

and for $\textbf{t} = \begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 1 \end{bmatrix}$ we have

\begin{equation} x_{\begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 1 \end{bmatrix}} = a_{\begin{bmatrix} 0 \\ 0 \end{bmatrix}} \xi_{\begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 1 \end{bmatrix}} + 
a_{\begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 1 \end{bmatrix}} 
\xi_{\begin{bmatrix} 0 \\ 0 \end{bmatrix} } \end{equation}

Is this the idea, except that in application we would sum over a larger set of index vectors? If so, what does it mean when the index on $\xi$ is not in the index set $\textbf{j}$? (as is the case in my experimental example where I have $\xi_{\begin{bmatrix} 0 \\ -1 \end{bmatrix}}$)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In dimension one, linear time series are usually defined by 
$$
x_t:=\sum_{j\in\mathbb Z}a_j\xi_{t-j},
$$
where $\left(\xi_i\right)_{i\in\mathbb Z}$ is independent and identically distributed with $\varepsilon_0$ centered and square integrable and $\sum_{j\in\mathbb Z}a_j^2$ is finite. In this way, the series is convergent.

In dimension two, this definition becomes 
$$
x_{t_1,t_2}=\sum_{j_1\in\mathbb Z}\sum_{j_2\in\mathbb Z}a_{j_1,j_2}\varepsilon_{t_1-j_1,t_2.j_2},
$$
where $\left(\xi_{i_1,i_2}\right)_{i_1,i_2\in\mathbb Z}$ is independent with $\varepsilon_{0,0}$ centered and square integrable and $\sum_{j_1,j_2\in\mathbb Z}a_{j_1,j_2}^2$ is finite. Here, the infinite sum is understood as the limit in $\mathbb L^2$ of the sequence $\left(x_{t_1,t_2}^{(m)}\right)_{m\geqslant 1}$ where 
$$x_{t_1,t_2}^{(m)}=\sum_{j_1=-m}^m\sum_{j_2=-m}^ma_{j_1,j_2}\varepsilon_{t_1-j_1,t_2.j_2}.$$
The same idea applies to dimension $d$.

Comment: To check my understanding; in 2 dimensions the $x$'s would come from a 2D grid and each $x$ would be determined by various linear combinations of of the $a$'s (from their own $a$ 2D grid) and the $\epsilon$'s (from their own $\epsilon$ 2D grid). In 3D the 'grids' would be a cubes and this idea would extend to higher dimensions in similar fashion.